# MPMoviePlayerController not playing local video

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

My video did not start to play in simple project
So I tried some examples to incorporate in the project.
First of all I added two frameworks MediaPlayer and MobileCoreService and imported .h file

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

Then added properties

```
@property (copy,   nonatomic) NSURL *movieURL;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *player;
```

And last step was adding to viewDidLoad next code

```
_movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Movie.m4v"];
_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:_movieURL];
_player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, 400, 300);
_player.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;
_player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
[self.view addSubview:_player.view];
[_player play];
```

Movie.m4v file in my root folder of application.

Also I'm trying to start it with help of action button, but code is  working with

```
[_player play];
```

but I get a black rectangle, and if I understand right my addSubview part is working
Searching another examples but almost find same realisation.
http://photokarma.bl.ee/ios/VideoTest.zip archive with src code and file

Answer (score 0):

Please resolve this line in Your code.

`_movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Movie.m4v"];`

if this is an `http` url then write complete like `http://www.yourserver.com/../../Movie.m4v`
or you accessing this video from locally within your `iOS` App then provide the full path like

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
```

then after finding the movie url you can `init` your player like

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(184, 200, 400, 300);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

As per your Comment `do you have any idea why i get urlpath nil?`

Check that:

The Movie file exists in your copy of the source code.Also review that `Xcode` project has a reference to that file (if it's red, it means the file isn't actually present)

In your target in Xcode, look at "Build Phases" and reveal the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase. That file should be present. If it isn't, press the + button and select it.

As per your given code i resolved and found this bug as i also discussed.
Tick both

- Add To Targets Your Project Name
- Copy item into your destination group

So you need to remove the video file and add it again with these both tick.

[image]

Comment: So, change path but app switching off after start 
Cant find problem in log because get next problem
error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Applications/D87BC244-3840-464C-AC65-1D76AC9887C4/VideoTest.app' -- failed to get the task for process 7471

Comment: and in xCode has issue(yellow) that my movieURL unused 
But i used it when init my player

Comment: And in my emulator debuger get next
2014-02-04 12:31:51.084 VideoTest[24687:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: do you have any idea why i get urlpath nil?

Comment: Make review but have same result =(
Add link of src folder to "Question"

Comment: esolved when you copy your video file you need to use add to targets and copy into destination bundles review updated answer. try to follow these steps.

Comment: it's help, but video don't playing now((
I'm testing on simulator on my iPad mini also(
Any result of videoplayback
i use your code with bundle

Answer (score 0):

Try This code..

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v" inDirectory:nil];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
player= [[ MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(184, 200, 400, 300);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

Source Code:http://ishare-edu.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-play-audio-and-video-in-iphone.html

Hope it works...

Comment: 2014-02-04 12:51:49.990 VideoTest[24909:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Nope =(

Comment: Keep your file(Movie.m4v) under classes..folder.
If you kept it any directory...Then give that directory path..at inDirectory place..

Comment: 2014-02-04 17:11:53.698 VideoTest[26470:70b] -[MPMoviePlayerViewController play]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa17a4e0
2014-02-04 17:11:53.703 VideoTest[26470:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MPMoviePlayerViewController play]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa17a4e0'
Next eeror ((

Comment: Download code using above Source Code link in my updated answer..It will help to load local video using MPMoviePlayerViewController..!@user3111850

Answer (score 0):

Try in Simple steps:

**Step 1:** Import `MediaPlayer` framework `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`

**Step 2:** Set delegate in `.h` file `UIViewController<MPMediaPlayback>`

**Step 3:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *fileLocation= [bundle pathForResource:@"file_video" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileLocation];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
}

-(void)endSeeking
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

-(void)stop
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Also failed =(
Vido don't play